# Travel insurance that cover expensive camera

Tags: insurance, electronic-items

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to insure professional equipment while traveling](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/4439/how-to-insure-professional-equipment-while-traveling)

How can I find a reasonably priced travel insurance that covers expensive photographic equipment (worth about £1500)? I used the popular search engines and comparison web sites, but they only return the cheapest insurance (with the worst conditions usually). I am after an worldwide annual multi-trip for UK residents.

The only company I found that has a special option for what they call gadgets is [insurefor.com](http://www.insurefor.com/). I was wondering how can I make a better comparison of the market.

Comment: May need to be merged with: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/4439/how-to-insure-professional-equipment-while-traveling.  See answer in the comments